# What in my code is causing the below error: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function begin() on null?

Tags: php, class, oop, interface

I have the below two Class objects and one interface object. However, I am getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function begin() on null

What am I missing here?

```
// First Class

class Template1
{
   protected $convert;

   public function convert()
   {
       echo $this->convert->begin();
   }

   public function setConvert(ITemplate $convert) // Interface is also passed through arguments in this function
   {
       $this->convert = $convert;
   }
};

// Interface

interface ITemplate
{
   public function begin();
};

// Second Class

class Template2 implements ITemplate
{
   private $message;

   public function begin() 
   {
       $this->message = "Hello World!";
       return $this->message;
   }
};

// Creating new objects 

$templateTwoObj = new Template2();

$templateOneObj = new Template1();
$templateOneObj->convert() ;


Hello World  //expected output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing:

```
$templateOneObj->setConvert($templateTwoObj);
```

before

```
$templateOneObj->convert();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D I totally forgot that I have to connect those two objects. Lol.